# How can I get an Angular 5 component element's position?

Tags: angular, components, render, angular5

In an angular 5 component I have a **table**, and I need to create something like overlaying multiple **div**s above several **td**'s. What's the best way to get the position of those **td**'s in the table so I can position the other elements?

I'm currently trying to use something like

```
@ViewChild('table')
tableElement: ElementRef

ngAfterViewChecked() {
    this.tableElement.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName('cell')
    // ...
}
```

But I'm risking some weird infinite loops doing it this way. Is there a way to know that a specific element was "redrawn", for instance?

Answer (score 2):

The methods proposed here did not work for me. Instead, I used the [`getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) along with [`window.innerHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerHeight).

From the `boundingRect`, add the top and height properties. If it is less than the `window.innerHeight`, it has become visible.

This method works with any framework (afaik). But here is an Angular example:

```js
import { ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

class ExampleComponent {
    constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
            const rect = this.el.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();

            if (rect.top + rect.height < window.innerHeight) {
                console.log('component is visible');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The "infinite" loop is normal cause you run the function in the AfterViewChecked lifecycle hook.

By design : `AfterViewChecked Lifecycle hook that is called after every check of a component's view.`

I would use `getBoundingClientRect` to get top, bottom, width, height etc. `const domRect = element.getBoundingClientRect();` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect, but I am not sure I understood which in which event you want to run the getElement. What do you mean by "redrawn" ? You can try to get the position after promise is been resolved if the data is coming dynamically.

Comment: I would like an event or something similar that get's called after the table is drawn and I can get the position of each element, so I can position the overlaying divs somehow.

Comment: as i mentioned in my answer if the data of the table is coming from the backend you will have to call the getBoundingClientRect() when the promise is resolved. If the data of the table is hard coded in the template  then ngAfterViewInit() should be fine. It is called only once.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you want to position an html element (the td) relative to another (the div). This seems to be a plain html and css issue.

You could position both elements in a containing box with

```
position: relative;
```

And the div that you want to position above should have following properties so that they overlap with your td

```
position: absolute;
top: /*your top value*/;
left: /*your left value*/;
```

If you really want to get the exact position of your td then you need to extract the top, bottom, right and left position via Javascript.

```
    this.tableElement.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName('cell').getBoundingClientRect();
```

Comment: I don't have the position of the TDs when positioning the DIVs, so it's not a CSS problem.

Comment: You don't need the position of the td to position a div accordingly. Alternatively use the option I mentioned below.

Answer (score 0):

One way: merge a stream from resize events and a subject. Instead of a subject, if you're fetching the data with http you could use the same observable you already have from there, like `http.get(...).pipe(share())`

```
import {merge} from 'rxjs/observable/merge';
import {fromEvent} from 'rxjs/observable/fromEvent';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject};
// ...
tableChange$:Subject<void> = new Subject();

ngOnInit() {
    merge(
         fromEvent(window, 'resize'),
         this.tableChange$
    ).subscribe(() => {
        this.tableElement.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName('cell')...
    }); // remember to unsubscribe this subscription at OnDestroy in real life
    this.tableChange$.next();
}
```

**Edit:**

It might be a cleaner & simpler solution to move this concern to a component you'd use inside those TDs. You can use `ng-content` to show whatever content inside the component, and get an elementRef by injecting it in the constructor. And if you still need to talk to the parent, use outputs.