# How to find coordinates of HTML element in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm new to Angular so a detailed explanation would be helpful.

I'm drawing several circles using the template below:

```
<div (window:resize)="onEatableResized($event)">
  <svg id="eater" (click)="onEaterClicked()"
      [@eater_circle_trigger]="eater_clicked ? 'eater_clicked' : 'none'"
      (@eater_circle_trigger.done)="onEaterDone($event)"
      [attr.width]=eater_data.box_size
      [attr.height]=eater_data.box_size>
        <circle cx="20" cy="20" stroke-width="1"
          [attr.r]=eater_data.radius
          [attr.stroke]=eater_data.stroke_color
          [attr.fill]=eater_data.fill_color>
        </circle>
  </svg>

  <svg *ngFor="let ncircles of total_circles|times; index as id"
    id="{{ 'eatable_' + id }}"
    [attr.width]=eatable_data.box_size
    [attr.height]=eatable_data.box_size>
      <circle cx="20" cy="20" stroke-width="1"
        [@eater_trigger]="id < current_eatable ? 'dead' : 'alive'"
              [attr.r]=eatable_data.radius
        [attr.stroke]=eatable_data.stroke_color
        [attr.fill]=eatable_data.fill_color
      />
    </svg>
</div>
```

It looks like this:

[image]

When the red circle is clicked, it moves to the next circle to the right using the trigger `eater_circle_trigger`:

```
animations: [
    trigger('eater_circle_trigger', [
      state('eater_clicked', style({
        transform: 'translate(35px, 0px)'
      })),
      transition('* => eater_clicked', [
        animate('1s ease-in-out')
      ])
    ]),
    trigger('eater_trigger', [
      state('dead', style({
        fill: 'white'
      })),
    ])
  ]
```

I'm using the `transform: 'translate(35px, 0px)'` and it works because I know it's position. I don't want it to work this way. I want to find the next circle's position and move the red circle there without using constant `translate(35px, 0px)`. It should be `'translate(' + xt + ', ' + ' yt ')'`, where `xt` and `yt` are coordinates of the next circle.

How can I do that in Angular? If there is a better solution, you can suggest that too.

Comment: Well, if you know that spacing between the circles, can't you just translate by that spacing times the number of translations you've done? For example, if we `let xSteps = 0, ySteps = 0;` and `const spacing = <whatever the spacing is, I guess 35px>;`, then just `\`translate(${xSteps * spacing}, ${ySteps * spacing})\`` and modify `xSteps` and `ySteps` based on where you want the circle to be within the grid.

Comment: @MattF.: That's one way of doing this thing. But I was wondering can it be avoided by directly getting the location of the element.

Comment: If you have the nth element, its location is (`(n % rowLength) * spacing`, `Math.floor(n / rowLength) * spacing`). I guess I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @MattF.: I'm looking for the Angular API (if any) which will provide me the location of the nth element so that I don't need to calculate it myself.

Comment: Then is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49636332/how-can-i-get-an-angular-5-component-elements-position) related?

Comment: @MattF.: I'll take a look later. Thanks.